# Adding notes in PDF from browser

Tags: javascript, pdf, browser

Is it possible to add notes in a PDF previewed in browser, using JavaScript?

We need to create a feature that allows users to add notes to PDF which directly has been displayed in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can use pdftron

https://www.pdftron.com/